# Override com_content views

Tags: joomla-4.x, overrides

I have created the following override files in my Joomla 4 template override folder:

/templates/chat/html/com_content/category/needinghomes.xml
/templates/chat/html/com_content/category/needinghomes.php
/templates/chat/html/com_content/category/needinghomes_children.php
/templates/chat/html/com_content/category/needinghomes_item.php

I then have a menu item (Menu Item Type is "Needing Homes") called 'Adopt', this gives me the following URL:

https://DOMAIN.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=chat:needinghomes&id=8&Itemid=121

This page is loading correctly, showing me categories (counties).

One of the counties is called "Bedfordshire" if I click on that, it takes me to this URL:

https://DOMAIN.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=needinghomes&layout=needinghomes_children&location=Bedfordshire&Itemid=121 but that page is showing an error:

"View not found [name, type, prefix]: needinghomes, html, site"

What am I doing wrong with the overrides that it's not finding the needinghomes view?

Comment: Are you intentionally building a route to `needinghomes` view or was it somehow generated by Joomla?